# can't access heroku console in cmd line

Tags: heroku

here's my stack info: 
Stack:         bamboo-mri-1.9.2

When I try to access the heroku console via the following command:
`heroku run -a pakrat script/rails console` (pakrat is my app name)

I get the following error:
/app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1032:in `initialize': could not translate host name "ec2-107-22-169-50.compute-1.amazonaws.com" to address: Name or service not known (PGError)
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1032:in`new'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1032:in `connect'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:301:in`initialize'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in `new'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:28:in`postgresql_connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in `new_connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in`checkout_new_connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in`loop'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in `block in checkout'
    from /usr/ruby1.9.2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`mon_synchronize'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in `checkout'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in`connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:107:in`retrieve_connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:703:in`table_exists?'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.1/lib/active_record/base.rb:798:in `attribute_names'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:168:in`_set_wrapper_defaults'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:128:in `inherited'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in`block (2 levels) in with'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in with'
    from /app/app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:1:in`'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`block in require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in`depend_on'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in`block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in`block in eager_load!'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in`eager_load!'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in`require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in`block in load_dependency'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in`load_dependency'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in`require_environment!'
    from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:39:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in`require'
    from script/rails:6:in `'

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was related to not being able to connect to postgres, so I promoted my database using heroku pg:promote as mentioned here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-addon

and heroku console works once again